# Qt Quick QML GridLayout with multiple rows and columns using JSON

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, grid-layout, qt-quick

I have below JSON that I want to display inside a GridLayout.
This JSON is received inside the QML file and assigned to an property.

```
{
    {
        "id":1
        "name": "abc1"
        "age": 10
        "city": "xvy"
        "gender": "m/f"
    },
    {
        "id":2
        "name": "abc2"
        "age": 10
        "city": "xvy"
        "gender": "m/f"
    },
    {
        "id":2
        "name": "abc3"
        "age": 10
        "city": "xvy"
        "gender": "m/f"
    }
}
```

I want to display this JSON in `5-Columns` and `3-Rows` GridLayout.
As shown in below table:

```
+---------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|   Id    |  Name              |  Age            |    City         |    Gender      |
+---------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1    |    TextFiled       | TextFiled       | TextFiled       | ComboBox       |
+---------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|    2    |    TextFiled       | TextFiled       | TextFiled       | ComboBox       | 
+---------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|    3    |    TextFiled       | TextFiled       | TextFiled       | ComboBox       |
+---------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Till now I have thought of a below solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 600; height: 400; visible: true

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 5
        rowSpacing: 2
        columnSpacing: 2
        anchors.margins: 5

        // example models
        property var id: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
        property var name: [ "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" ]
        property var age: [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ]
        property var city: [ "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" ]
        property var gender: [ "m", "f", "m", "f", "m" ]

        Repeater {
            model: grid.id
            Label {
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.column: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: grid.name
            TextFiled {
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.column: 1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: grid.age
            TextFiled {
                Layout.row: index
                Layout.column: 2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text: modelData
            }
        }


        // And rest of Repeater for next columns 
        // ....

    }
}
```

Is this the correct approach?
Additionally I want to save the updated values from ComboBox and TextFiled from the grid is to the JSON, how can I do that?

Comment: I think you can make the display work by using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function in a two-level Repeater setup

Comment: If you have a proper model behind this, maybe use the new TableView, and DelegateChooser for the delegate.

Comment: @Amfasis: I am not very sure what is Object.keys() can you please explain in details.

Comment: @Mitch: I think DelegateChooser fits for this requirement but nowt sure how to use it in this case as I am new to QML. Also I want to save the updated input values from the user.

Comment: the Object.keys() method gives you a list of all keys in an object (say the first object) which you can feed to a Repeater, that way the Repeater will instantiate the delegate for every column you have

Comment: @Amfasis: It is hard to understand how to use Object.keys() will it possible to provide a sample/example demonstrating how it can be used in context of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you've provided incorrect JSON (I've fixed it) I would use the following solution. The same solution can be based on Object.keys(), as @Amfasis already mentioned but in this case all the properties should be on the same order in all the array's objects.

```js
Component {
    id: tableHeader
    Text {
        text: modelData
        font.bold: true
    }
}

Component {
    id: tableCell
    Repeater {
        property var arr: modelData
        model: layout.cols.length
        delegate: Text {
            text: arr[layout.cols[index]]
        }
    }
}

GridLayout {
    id: layout
    columns: 5
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10
    property var cols: ['id','name','age','city','gender']
    property var json: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "abc1",
            "age": 10,
            "city": "xvy",
            "gender": "m/f"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "abc2",
            "age": 20,
            "city": "xvy",
            "gender": "m/f"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "abc3",
            "age": 30,
            "city": "xvy",
            "gender": "m/f"
        }
    ]

    Repeater {
        model: layout.cols
        delegate: tableHeader
    }

    Repeater {
        model: layout.json
        delegate: tableCell
    }
}
```

Comment: This will generate table cells with only Text and I need to generate cells in a row with different components as Text, TextFiled and ComboBox as mentioned and example table given in the question. Also I need to save the updated value in the cells to targeted JSON.

Comment: you didn't mention that but anyway, you can use different delegate components depends on the column index.